# What's the best way to avoid catastrophe caused by negligence?

Tags: programming-practices, debugging, bug

I have been a programmer for almost 1 year.

As an ADHD adult, naturally I don't have the same strength of attention on ordinary stuffs as my colleagues do.

And I find the catastrophe made by me are usually caused by trivial negligence.

Like for today, I found the cron process on the server collapsed in the morning.

After half hour of debugging. I found I wrote in the cron

`* 4 * * * sh daily_task.sh`

instead of

`0 4 * * * sh daily_task.sh`

Which runs the huge shell 59 times in the morning instead of the intended 1 time.

Is there some kind of cultivatable behaviour or some tools or anything that can help me at least reduce such kind of  mistake?

How do you do to avoid such kind of mistake?

Comment: by writing tests? Most of the time, automated testing helps, sometimes a quick manual testing is useful, for e.g. in this particular case, testing your expression with: http://www.cronmaker.com/ could've helped.

Comment: You need to pay attention. That takes practice. I don't take anything I do for granted. I double check everything. Learn to pause and look. After typing a command, wait a moment, and see if anything comes to you. Something else I do, often, is go get someone else to look at what I'm about to do if it's important. I don't have to do that, but it builds community and trust.

Comment: When you're done, grab a rubber duck and explain what you did, one step a time, justifying each step.

Comment: You can reduce how many mistakes you make, but your model of how to avoid catastrophe should never be based on *not making mistakes*. It should be based on systems in place (like automated tests, Doc Brown's four-eyes-principle, etc.) that stop the mistakes you *will* make from leading to catastrophe.

Comment: Write a list of things you have completed as you go along. The next day go back and check them over to see if they still make sense.

Comment: This is most definitely *not* the kind of mistake you need to have ADHD to make. In the absence of code reviews, anyone can and will make these sort of mistakes sooner or later.

Comment: @JoelEtherton If he intended to use that as an excuse, he wouldn't be asking for solutions. Surely he only mentions it because he feels he needs solutions that might be deemed overkill for the average person.

Comment: @Doval: If it wasn't an excuse then it would never have come up. The mistake described here has nothing to do with that condition, and it's commonly made by many people who do not have that condition.

Comment: I have ADD myself, and between that and other adverse experiences I've developed a certain policy for work that I accept and do. Nearly every time I catch myself in violation of this, it's because some feces has collided with an active turbine: ***Don't trust anyone's work but your own - and triple-check that, too***. Oversights like this are typically a failure of the latter part of that policy. You might not be able to stay focused on one job enough to do it right all in one go, but make sure to go back and verify it at some point before submitting it.

Comment: @JoelEtherton "The mistake described here has nothing to do with that condition, and it's commonly made by many people who do not have that condition." Except he may make mistakes *more often* than people without the condition, and that matters, because checking for errors isn't free. Be honest - you don't write a formal proof for every function you write. There's a cost-benefit analysis involved in deciding when and how thoroughly to check for errors, so the fact that he feels his rate of mistakes is high is significant. Saying "just check everything twice" is a cop out.

Comment: @Doval: And if there wasn't an ADHD diagnosis (which no longer seems to be a disorder since a very large number of people claim it), would it change anything about this if there was an admission of a high rate of mistakes? Read the answers and comments. Not one suggests anything relative to that condition. Every response to help manage an overage of mistakes can be applied regardless of the condition. *It's a crutch*, and people need to stop leaning on it. If you'd like to take it to a chat room, feel free to create one.

Comment: ADHD is a real syndrome with real symptoms and a real impact on productivity. The fact that it may be exaggerated or misdiagnosed doesn't mean that it's imaginary.  

There are specific things that ADHD sufferers can do to help them perform better which might not be helpful to non-sufferers. While the suggestions made here are good for anyone in general, many ADHD sufferers are helped by using certain specific techniques, such as listening to background music or white noise, squeezing a rubber ball with the fingers, and making rituals out of important behavior.

Comment: I have asked a very similar question on [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16533) and [CogSci](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5994). Mine was phrased in the context of performing lab experiments, but should be very readily applicable to programming.

Comment: to add on to dmcdivitt's comment, *this is what you get paid for*. to overthink everything, double check everything, and not make a lot of mistakes. that's like half of being a programmer.

Comment: @JoelEtherton The argument that "a whole bunch of people claim to be it, so it must not be true" is a little specious.  If I'm a truly incredibly guitarist, and then a whole bunch of mediocre or bad guitarists come along and claim to be incredible, that doesn't then imply that I'm no longer an incredible guitarist.  That's not how logic works.

Comment: @asteri: I didn't say it is no longer true, I said when it becomes as common as it is, it is no longer a disorder it is the norm. However, don't take my word for it. Do your own research. Even the psychologist who came up with it called it a "fabricated disease".

Comment: Ironically enough, I just did this same thing the other day. We were wondering why it backed up so many copies of our GitLab...

Answer (score 47):

> Is there some kind of cultivatable behaviour [...] that can help me at least reduce such kind of mistake

Absolutely, it is called **four-eyes-principle**.

If you had you shown your crontab entry to a second person (a person knowing cron, of course), chances are high the mistake would have been avoided.

In programming, when it comes to this, people mostly think of code-reviews, but that is actually the same thing.

Comment: I would also add running it in a test environment first if possible.

Comment: @JeffO: Of course, and there is a good chance if he had shown the thing to someone else, that person might have told him the same.

Answer (score 15):

You don't need ADHD to have this problem. It might be that you are working in environment where you get interrupted often or where you have to work on many things at the same time. So loosing track of your progress or making small mistakes is almost guaranteed.

There is one thing you can do to reduce those errors : tests based on specification.

First, you write down the specification in the most detailed way you can. In case of code, this should be in form of automated tests. Best way is to follow TDD. So when you suddenly get distracted, then your tests will tell you what you have already done and allow you to quickly pick up where you ended. Also, it makes regression testing easier.

In a case, where testing code is not possible, make sure you have someone else to go over what you have created and have them test the software according to the specification. You should always test software in testing environment before it goes into production. The issue you are talking about would be easily caught by running it for a day in testing environment and checking the logs.

Comment: Yes, I was interrupted quite often by colleagues from other department such as the Marketing department, with their `wonderful` new plan or data request.

Comment: It helps to have someone else look at your changes even when testing is possible, and the technique is called pair-programming. At first it feels like you are working slower but long term you are working faster because of increased quality and raised bus factor. What would be the chances of doing this error if two people were doing the change?

Answer (score 12):

You always have to be at least two steps away from disaster. That means you never directly push something you just wrote into production. You either test it, or you have it tested, or you have it reviewed, or figure out some other way to have a two step path to disaster. Sometimes I will leave something for the next day and review my work again before committing.

In cases where something is really critical, you add a third step: a second reviewer, a second independent test, etc...

To err is human. Our brains are not built for precision. Everyone makes mistakes, everyone writes bugs, although some more than others (being careful still pays). You have to figure out a process that builds in the assumption that any individual's work is flawed.

Answer (score 6):

Previous answers mentioned two points:

- **Reviews.**
- **Testing.**

but there are also three additional elements which may help:

- **Better visualization.**

  By using tools which let you better visualize what you do, you may catch errors earlier. This is particularly illustrative with the cron jobs. Imagine you have a visualization tool which shows you, graphically, when the cron jobs you have defined run. Immediately, you see that there is something wrong.

  Syntax highlighting, for example, is the most popular developers' visualization tool, and it indeed [helps finding errors at very early stages](http://blog.pelicandd.com/article/93/should-students-be-using-syntax-highlighting) (often within seconds of writing something wrong), before compiler or tests run.
- **Continuous monitoring.**

  Why the server collapsed? Wasn't there a way to see that something is going wrong *before* bad things happened?

  Servers should have been properly monitored. Either a person or an app should have seen that after the last change, CPU usage increased from, say, an average of 42% to an average of 100%, and could do something to prevent the server to collapse.

  This leads me to Continuous integration, and more specifically Continuous deployment. In Continuous deployment, when you make a commit, the new revision is built, tested and deployed to production on a few servers. Then, those servers are watched by an app. If the app sees an abnormal increase in resources usage or an abnormal quantity of warnings in syslog coming from those servers, the servers are reverted to their previous state.
- **Strictness.**

  Guidelines and rules are usually annoying (not convinced? Try to write a small C# app which conforms to StyleCop and Code analysis and has good results with Code metrics and has a decent code coverage!) but also particularly useful. This is why some projects target zero warnings with static checkers and zero warnings with the compiler set to a maximum level: errors found earlier are errors you don't have to solve when it is too late.

  While this wouldn't help with cron jobs, it helps when writing code.

Answer (score 4):

I think the direct solution, especially to the sort of problem you exemplified, is to *make mistakes conspicuous*.

If you look at the two lines you gave, the difference is actually quite subtle. You have to have a lot of detailed, nuanced syntax "in your mind" when reading it if you want to catch the mistake. You also have to keep an eye out for hard-to-see visual features (`*` and `0` can be easy to confuse).

For example, in your example, if `cron` syntax was like the following:

```
minute=0 hour=4 day=every week=every month=every year=every
```

You would be less likely to confuse it with:

```
minute=every hour=4 day=every week=every month=every year=every
```

You can't really change cron's syntax, but you *could* write a simple CLI program for yourself that takes named arguments like above, and then pass them to the actual `cron`. You'd need to carefully review the code that converts from your named arguments, but you only need to do that once, so you can afford to really focus yourself and go the extra mile in error checking - print out the code, read and explain it to yourself aloud and so on.

When you have a program like this, you can also add a sanity check. After you make a new cron job, have it output:

```
This new job will run 1 times a day.
```

(perhaps it tries to find the shortest time period that results in a whole number)

Now it will be really difficult for you to make the same mistake. Your tradeoff is:

1. It now takes more keystrokes to type the commands, and they look busier (this is probably why `cron` was given the syntax that it was in the first place).
2. You have spent time and effort setting up the error-resistant interface model and the sanity check (but in this case you can probably do it in an hour or two).

Now, I'm not necessarily suggesting you do this for `cron`. That seems like it's a bit of overkill, unless you set and edit tasks on `cron` very often. I just used your example to illustrate the two useful tricks: Sanity checks, and preferring syntax that makes errors very conspicuous even if you don't look for them. The idea is to make sure that mistakes [smell](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/).

With syntax, the two obvious things you can do are:

1. Select tools and languages that have more error-resistant syntax, for instance, C# vs. Perl. Notice again the tradeoff between catching mistakes quickly and having to do more work.
2. Wrap poor syntax in better syntax. For instance, make your own wrapper function for a poorly named functions with ambiguous argument names, make your own wrapper program for arcane tools, use an editor that supports color highlighting and so on.

It doesn't make sense to do these all the way all the time. You want to ask yourself, what matters more in a given task: Correctness, or your time? It's no use disputing that hacking together a quick script in Perl is going to get the job faster than writing a well-structured C# program with clear OOP hierarchy. If you're not worried about mistakes, and you're in a hurry, why bother? But keep in mind that every time you take this shortcut, you are making a gamble: You wager much frustration and gnashing of teeth on the hope that you won't have to go back and extend on your project in the far future, long after you've forgotten how it was supposed to work (or that you won't realize halfway through that your original design won't work, and now must be radically altered).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with all of the other answers, but the idea of **defensive coding** could also help here.

When practicing defensive coding, we write our code under the assumption that it's going to be used incorrectly; whether by us, or someone else. In this case, your shell script has been used incorrectly (run 59 times instead of once).

How could we defend against that? A simple but crude way would be to log a timestamp somewhere at the beginning of the run, and only run if the timestamp is found and more than, say, 20 hours old.

The problem with that coarse-grained approach is that we might want to manually trigger the script, eg. if some part of its functionality needs to be run again, but not all of it. In that case, a finer-grained approach would be better, eg. "if the latest DB backup is more than 20 hours old, backup the DB", "if the last announcement was sent out more than 20 hours ago, send out an announcement", etc.

Comment: Or just add a --force option marked "for manual use only", possibly requiring an attached interactive terminal to query… though theneyouehave to test THAT…

Answer (score 1):

As well as testing...

I found that printing out the code on paper, then running the code in a debugger and ticker each line once I confirm that all the values were as expected in the debugger was a great way.   This gets you to look at your code in **another** way.

Driving the "debugger checking" with unit tests is nice...

Comment: I did a thing where I wanted to update a few columns in a single row of a database table. Of course, I didn’t realize I missed specifying  the row's ID and so it updated every row. Fortunately, I was able to recover everything from copy of production, and all of the data is back (the IDs aren't as consistent as I'd like them to be but at least our production apps work again). Now, if you really don't know what to do, it's better to ask someone for help instead of trying to fix problems and potentially make everything worse in the process.